# How to make swappable div 'ui cards' with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

For example if you had a wizard that had step by step directions asking for information, each div would have the controls needed for each step (only one div shows at a time). Then you would swap through them one by one, hence going through a multi-step process all in one page load. Is this pretty easy to do in jQuery? Could you have one form span across multiple divs and submit all at once?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, just use the .hide() and .show() to show/hide the appropriate DIV at the right time.

Yes, forms can span across multiple divs and you can submit at the end.

Also, take a look at this plugin:

http://worcesterwideweb.com/jquery/wizard/

It basically does what I described.

Comment: This wizard is full of bugs. There are better wizards out there.